# Is there any other more efficient way to perform vector similarity search within PostgreSQL besides pgvector?

Tags: postgresql

I have some vectors generated from sentence transformer embeddings, and I want to store them in a database. My goal is to be able to retrieve similar vectors from the database based on a given reference sentence.
To be more specific, suppose I have a table containing some vector data.
{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5, 6},
{7, 8, 9}``
I want to figure out which one of these 3 vectors is closest (in Euclidean distance) to vector {5, 5, 5}.
In my scenario, a vector will have 768 dimensions.
I have tried using pgvector, but both the index build time and search speed were unsatisfactory.

Comment: At 768 dimensions, you are unlikely to do better than a full scan.  You would need to highly optimize this full scan, which will be very hard to do inside PostgreSQL due to the overhead imposed by ACID compliance and it Advanced Data Type system.